# Dropdown Column Selection in Document List Links to a Document (SharePoint 2010)

Tags: document-library, hyperlink, dropdown

I currently have a document library where I (additionally) have a '*Choice (menu to choose from)* column with a bunch of select-able items. Ideally, I'd like to have the user select an item when they create their new document, and that item chosen links to a document that they can click on for more information (the selected item would be something like... "Fall Hazards", and would link to a document or reference about fall hazards that would open up in the respected Word or PDF reader).

So in effect, it'd be like a dropdown list of links, but I know the '*Choice*' column type doesn't allow link references by default (that I know of), and the '*Hyperlink*' column type only allows for 1 per row. Is there a way to make this happen? I tried using the '*Lookup*' column in hopes of getting the "name" field that is created for the file-name a possible choice that contained the link. If this is something I can do through a workflow or coding, could someone give me an overview of what I'd need to do?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use a separate list to maintain your text and related hyperlinks, you can use additional columns in lookup field. For example, create a custom list with a custom column url. The title field will be your main lookup field (fire hazards) but url will be additional field which links to a document in a library.

[Check this screen shot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LlVFU.png)

Comment: Thank you! Your response sparked additional digging, and I ended up filling in the Title field which (I didn't realize) automatically creates a link when you select the document library you're tying the lookup to. I thought it shared the field's property. I tried creating a Hyperlink column in that other list, but it wouldn't let me choose that new column in the additional fields section of the Lookup column editor. Only shared fields like Title, ID and Version (which I think is by design)

Comment: Happy that it helped in some way.